# how can I move to the next item in the array if its UUID match with a string(autoIncrement) react native

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, arraylist

need to ignore the Question if UUID already exits in completed questions and skip to next question 
auto-increment is not working when I'm using this.setState({autoIncrement:this.state.autoIncrement+1}) this to skip to the next question

here are my **constructor variables**

```
 const = randomQuestions:[{
        "uuid": "sjdfhgs-wer-1231456",
        "question": "What is Lorem Ipsum?",
        "options": ["a", "b", "c"],
        "currectAns": "a"
    },
    {
        "uuid": "sjdfhgs-wer-1241235",
        "question": "Why do we use it?",
        "options": ["a", "b", "c"],
        "currectAns": "b"
    },
    {
        "uuid": "sjdfhgs-wer-1233233",
        "question": "Where does it come from?",
        "options": ["a", "b", "c"],
        "currectAns": "a"
    },
    {
        "uuid": "sjdfhgs-wer-1243453",
        "question": "Where can I get some?",
        "options": ["a", "b", "c"],
        "currectAns": "c"
    }
],
const = autoIncrement:0,
const = completedQuestions:["sjdfhgs-wer-1233233"]
```

**here are my two functions**

```
generateQuestion(){ //here is my Question generation Function
if(!completedQuestions.includes(randomQuestions[autoIncrement].uuid)){
this.state.completedQuestions.push(randomQuestions[autoIncrement].uuid) //it will add after choosing the answer
this.setState({autoIncrement:this.state.autoIncrement+1})
}else{
  this.generateNextQuestion(); //skip to next Question if randomQuestions UUID includes in completedQuestions
}
}

 generateNextQuestion(){
this.setState({autoIncrement:this.state.autoIncrement+1}) //this is not working
this.generateQuestion()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array find function to get the first not completed question

```
const nextQuestion = randomQuestions.find((question) => {
  return !completedQuestions.includes(question.uuid);
});
```

Comment: this is okay for the first time. but I need to check every item in randomQuestions were it's completed or not?

Comment: then change `.find` for `.filter`, it will return a new array with all uncompleted questions